# PHP file_get_contents - Make a temporary local file?

Tags: php

Yes, I know the title is confusing enough, but here is what I want to do:

I have created 3 websites (for clients. I have no control over them). All of these sites load a certain page of my main website. (with PHP file_get_contents - lets name it www.mainsite/x.php).

The problem here is the bandwidth. I'd like the 10 websites to create some temporary local file with that x.php file, rather then load the www.mainsite/x.php file every time. However I may make some changes to that x.php file so the local file should update itself every week or so.

Again what I mean is:
website 1,2 and 3 has a PHP file_get_contents of www.mainsite/x.php. On first load it should create a x.html file with the contents of x.php (i.e: www.website1/x.html). After a week website 1,2 and 3 should load www.mainsite/x.php again and create a new x.html file if changes have been made to the www.mainsite/x.php file.

Comment: use a cronjob to get the contents every week. That way you can create a HTML file locally and edit it every week. You might even be able to create a history with that. Creating a file is not very hard.

Comment: forgot to mention that I do not control the 3 websites anymore, only the mainsite with the php file. What can I do then?

Comment: tell them (those external site) to load from your site frequently. or anytiime when you change your x.html, call them thru' telephone and tell them to update :)

Comment: Then it isn't really an option to reduce traffic, since they will still keep polling your website. You might want to gzip it, since that will help a little. You can't do alot more except compressing here. Also, I must agree with @PaulDinh. That would be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function generateTempFile(){
    $path = 'YOUR PATH';
    $original_path = 'YOUR ORIGINAL PATH WHICH you can change';

    if(file_exists($path)){
        $file_created_time = filemtime($path);
        if($file_created_time + 24*60*60 > time()){
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    $string = file_get_contents($original_path);
    return file_put_contents($path, $string);   
}
```

This function will check the file last modification and if its more than 24 hours it will rewrite it.. To start it just run it from a cron task or put it inside your code at some page which is openned each day to be sure that it will be runned..

At $string you have to set file new content and you can do that with file_get_contents()  from other file.. OR just generate some string at custom..

Comment: @HiddenChampion , keep in mind this code would have to run on the other servers. "forgot to mention that I do not control the 3 websites anymore"

Comment: @VolkerK sure, thanks for letting me know. This community is really nice.

Comment: @Svetlio the codes work great, but the page ends with the code. It won't display any other code that comes after it. How can I fix that?

Comment: Also if I use "public function" I get an error. Removing it works fine. I still have the problem of the site not displaying anything that comes after this code (css, html or php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists($pathtofile)){
return file_get_contents($pathtofile);
}else{
$newFileHtml=file_get_contents($webpathtogenerate);
file_put_contents($pathtofile,$newFileHtml);
return $newFileHtml;
}
```

then you have a crond script that runs once a week and erases the "cache" files